# How do i do a flip animation on pop view controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-animation

I have a flip animation which goes like this:

```
Picker *picker = [[Picker alloc] init];

            [self.navigationController pushViewController:picker animated:NO];

            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                             animations:^{ 
                                 [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
                                 } 
                             completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             }];
            [picker release];
```

This works perfectly. But when i want to do popViewController to get back, like this:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^{ 

                         [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
                     } 
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     }];
```

But this doesn't work, just goes back to the view without animating.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried calling `popViewControllerAnimated` **after** the animation ends?

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks. For future reference, I didn't put it in completion, i put it in the line just before that.

Comment: Also, i changed it to animated:YES to stop it from lagging. Somehow this worked.

Comment: @Andrew Have you figured out why this works if placed in animations^{} and not in completion^() ? I am happy that this approach for me but I really want to understand why it works that way ?

Answer (score 0):

Put the popViewController call inside your completion block, so it animates first and then pops.